# Can I use Stack Overflow Documentation as primary documentation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, documentation

Let's say I'm developing some kind of framework. Could I use Stack Overflow Documentation as the primary documentation?

This would require two things:

1. Getting full access to features for the tag (after some kind of verification to make sure I am the rightful owner)
2. Some method to freeze specific examples as best practice so every edit on that particular topic would need my approval.

Are these features available right now? If not, will they ever be?

Answer (score 4):

No, not in the form that you describe. In order for a topic to be created, three users with some rep in the tag have to commit to it. So, your framework would need to be established in Q&A, with at least a few people asking and answering questions about it.

It's fine if projects that have this kind of establishment want to move their documentation efforts over to Docs, but that would tend to happen pretty organically for any framework with a core of folks using / developing it.

Comment: What about projects that have no documentation to begin with and are waiting to be established through Q&A because the authors really, really, really like Stack Overflow?

Comment: @BoltClock *pssh* you act like people would just let SO do all the work for them, like support forums, docs. Oh, wait...