# Can I use Stack Overflow to host documentation examples?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I'm the author of an [open source project](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0#readme) and I'm documenting it in three forms:

- reference (Doxygen and Sphinx),
- book-like tutorials (JupyterBooks),
- and "how-to" examples.

I expect the "how-to" examples to be the most important part of the documentation.

**Is it permissible for me to write the "how-to" examples as a collection of self-answered Stack Overflow questions?**

I know that [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) has been discontinued. Unlike [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328466/can-i-use-stack-overflow-documentation-as-primary-documentation), it would only be *part* of my documentation.

Also, this software project already has a community on Stack Overflow with a tag: [awkward-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awkward-array). My intent would be to build up these "how-to" examples as a starter set, showing minimally reproducing examples not just to demonstrate the software, but also to demonstrate how to ask focused questions, hopefully to lead by example.

Is what I'm describing allowed?

Comment: It's very hard to do so and avoid being viewed as "excessive self promotion" on top of the fact writing good *questions* is very hard when you know the answer - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-do-i-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting.

Comment: Many projects include examples as part of their documentation, usually as part of a tutorial or user guide. That's almost certainly a better idea.

Comment: Self answering your own question is something that is allowed. If your question/answer is good  and doesn't seem to be trying to "self promote" I don't see the issue.

Comment: Make sure you make clear at the very start of a question that it is a self-answered example & that it is of small scope. Because in modern times how-to is susceptible to downvote for lack of research & to closure as too broad. Maybe check out a proposed example Q&A on meta.

Comment: Yes, you can post a self-answered question, but it has to be a good question. That's the gist of it. You might be better off just adding proper documentation to the project's repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How-to examples sounds like a good fit for self-answered Q&A. Keep the following things in mind:

- The question of a self-answered Q&A must uphold the same quality standards as any other question on the site. In particular, it needs to be *specific*, with a narrow scope. There must be a clear problem statement. The question should preferably have some example code demonstrating the problem, in the form of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
- Anyone will be able to answer the question, moderate the post or comment on it, like any other post.
- If you wish that others should be able to contribute to the technical contents, consider posting as "community wiki".

Some examples of self-answered Q&A, both converted to community wiki:
[How should character arrays be used as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526131/how-should-character-arrays-be-used-as-strings)
[Crash or "segmentation fault" when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ)

Alternatively consider using tag wiki as documentation in some cases. The tag wiki should contain tag usage guidelines, but may also contain technical information at some extent. Particularly, it is good for explaining what something *is*, rather than how something works. Check out the community FAQ: [How do I write a good tag wiki? Is it okay to use/copy content published elsewhere?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318337/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki-is-it-okay-to-use-copy-content-published-elsewhe).

Comment: "The question of a self-answered Q&A must uphold the same quality standards as any other question on the site." [You'd like to think so, at least...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396173/are-we-playing-favorites-with-high-rep-users-self-answering-off-topic-questions)

Answer (score -5):

Yes, you can. You can create self-answered posts.

The rule is that if you have some affiliation with the software, *you need to disclose it.* Simply put below all your answers, "I am the main developer of the awkward lib".

Furthermore, that the self-answers work as your documentation, is a no-issue for the system. Thus:

- If someone writes a better answer and there answer gets more ups, then that answer will be before yours.
- If someone wants, they can freely edit your question and answer with the required privilege (2000 for at will editing and a passed suggested edit review below that).
- Your questions and answers can be downvoted, closed and deleted on the usual rules.

This third is the largest problem. However, self-answered posts are typically liked by the community, and deletion requires closure before (in most cases).

So you need to defend the content against the closure. As you plan to write examples, *try to make your questions not too narrow*. *The questions should not ask for an example code, they should ask for some specific concept in your lib! And then, the answer should answer this specific concept, extending with the example.*

Note, python is a popular technology among beginner programmers not knowing how to ask, and this made the python reviewers a little bit more allergic than they should be. But, having 3k, you already probably have the required experience for that.

Most reviews will happen by checking the question and the answer independently from the other. *So make the question answerable also by others*. Probably it won't happen, but the question will need to be answerable *on the SO rules* also by others knowing your library well.

There is yet another problem, it is possible that someone will think that you only want to get a lot of rep, or that you want to advertise your own library. While I believe, as long as you provide high quality content for the site, there is nothing bad with them ([more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331645/259412)), others might have an irrational urge to stop you. Thus, count with a more negative than rational resistance already before you start to post.

Note also, you can edit/commit/push the documentation of your software any time if you want. On SO, many repeated edits to old posts are strongly disliked, because they contaminate the main page of the site.

In your case, I would first start with a single self-answered question and then I would wait, what happens. If the system accepts it, then post the next two. And so on.

If you get revenge downs or chain downs, *never forget to flag it*, even if you see no visible results or your flags are declined! No mod/CM will say to you, "I found that X voted you down so I warned him", it is forbidden for them.

If you are treated unfairly, *violating even the rules of the SO*, then come here to the meta, and initiate a consultation, what could be done to improve (don't say "This .... people unfairly closed my question!" instead your attitude should be "I believe it is not a too broad problem, because ..... What could be done to improve it?")

If you get critical comments, *take care of them*. They could have voted you down/close even without any comment, and for any comments there multiple user thinking the same but not saying anything.

If you follow all of these, I think you will get a lot of visits, upvotes and popularity.

While I believe, you deserve the rep by putting your doc here, you can also consider making your self-answered posts community wiki. You can community wiki only from your own answers, but (ideally, after at least some days of timeout), you can also politely ask the mods in a flag to convert your question to CW. Doing that, you would give up the rep you get from the possible ups and I can't see too much gain in it, but it is a possible option.

Comment: Way too much focus on rep, vigilantism and being popular. That's all noise.

Comment: @Cerbrus No-no, rep and popularity are central things in volunteer internet contributions. Vigilantism is not in the post (it is also hard to interpret, how would it be a problem - the majority of the moderation decisions are being done by the votes of ordinary community members, by design).